# How to update data model using DispatchQueue.main.async/Block/Closures in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, closures, capture-list

I am learning Swift. I have one Problem.

**Problem**- I have DataModel with image url, So first time will download image from url and of course  second time won't. So when I am getting image in my block I want to update my data model with image. But its not working.

- I have tried with inout function
- Also completionHander call back

**ViewController.swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OffersTableCell", for: indexPath) as! OffersTableCell

    var model = offersArray[indexPath.row] as! OffersModel
    cell.updateOfferCellWith(model: model, completionHandler: { image in
        model.image = image
    })///// I am getting image here, but model is not getting update
    return cell
}
```

**Cell.Swift**

```
func updateOfferCellWith(model: OffersModel, completionHandler:@escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {

    if (model.image != nil) { //Second time this block should be execute, but model image is always nil
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.offerImageView.image = model.image
        }
    }
    else{
        //First time- Download image from URL
        ImageDownloader.downloadImage(imageUrl: model.offerImageURL) { [weak self] image in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {[model] in
                var model = model
                self?.offerImageView.image = image
                //model.image = image*//This is also not working*
                completionHandler(image)*//Call back*
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `OffersModel` a `struct`?

Comment: This is a dangerous way because if the user scrolls and the cell goes off screen you'll get unpredictable behavior. Please take a look at [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Yes @Sulthan, it was struct. Now I have changed it on Class and its working. For now I removed the completionHandler call back and updating directly when its Done. BTW if we use completionHandler we have to noescaping, which is by default in Swift 3... is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments `model` is a `struct`.

When passing a `struct` (or any value type) to a method or assigning it to a variable, the `struct` is copied.

Therefore `model.image = image` is actually assigning `image` to a brand new `model` and not to the original `model`.

Using a reference type (a `class`) will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a potential solution based on your code, however, this is as vadain said in the comments, a bit dangerous because the image loading is asynchronous and could return the image at a time when the cell no longer exists.

Ideally what you want to do is set up your model in such a way that it is persistent and it should send the async request to download it's image.  Then, when the image comes back it update the model and the model broadcasts a message saying that it's image has been update.  The cells can listen and respond to updates to the model while they exist.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OffersTableCell", for: indexPath) as! OffersTableCell

    var model = offersArray[indexPath.row] as! OffersModel

    if image = model.image {
        // setting directly here... you could call an image on the cell if you want more data encapuslation
        cell.offerImageView.image = model.image
    } else {
        ImageDownloader.downloadImage(imageUrl: model.offerImageURL) { [weak self] image in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                model.image = image
                cell.offerImageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```